# how I should set text into my textfield that is on tableview?

Tags: swift, delegates, tableview, textfield

i have this problem, I have a table view with a custom cell, the custom cell has a text field, I should put text in this textfield with a custom button, the button is out of the tableview. 
my problem is, how I can set text into textfield? and my other problem is that I can't identify the current textfield for set text, I only know the tag.

this is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! budgetCellTableViewCell
  cell.insertText.delegate = self
  cell.insertText.tag = indexPath.row
  cell.insertText.inputView = UIView()
  cell.showViews()
  if let money = arrayData[indexPath.row]["amount"]
  {
        cell.showSubtitle.text = "Ultimos 30 dias: \(money)"
  }
  if let cat = arrayData[indexPath.row]["category"]
  {
        cell.showTitle.text = cat as? String
  }
  cell.selectionStyle = .none
  return cell
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {


    if self.textFieldTagActive == textField.tag
    {
        textField.text = setText
    }
    else
    {
        self.setText = ""
        self.textFieldTagActive = textField.tag
    }


func addNumber(_ number: Int) {

    if number != -1
    {
        setText += String(number)
    }
    else
    {
        setText.removeLast()
    }
}
```

the function addNumber is used when I push my custom button
with the function textFieldDidBeginEditing I get the textfield tag, I push my custom button and finally I push the same textfield and the text appears in the textfield, but I really want push my button and the same time, the text appears into textfield

so, how I can set text into my textfield since my custom button that is out of tableview?

thanks

Comment: If you know the tag, then you know the row.  Just [reload the cell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) at that row.  The `cellForRowAt` will run again - AND at that time, update the textfield

Comment: Use the fast enumeration to look for the text field with the right tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the current text field from delegate functions.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentText = "your text"
    var currentTF: UITextField?

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        // set text to the text field.
        currentTF?.text = currentText
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // get the text field that you want
        currentTF = textField
        return true
    }
}
```